# How to return all rows from DataRow.GetChildRows()

Tags: c#

I have a `System.Data.DataRow` with a relation to another table in a `DataSet`. I am calling

```
var childRows = dr.GetChildRows("childRelation")
```

But this will only return certain rows (Original, Added, Modified). It does not return Deleted rows even when I specify DataRowVersion.Default I'd expect it to considering the summary text for `Default` is

> The default version of System.Data.DataRowState. For a DataRowState
>   value of Added, Modified or Deleted, the default version is Current.
>   For a System.Data.DataRowState value of Detached, the version is
>   Proposed.

How can I get all child rows regardless of version or state?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `.Select` on the child rows as opposed to getting the child rows from the parent.

```
var desiredRowStates = (DataViewRowState.Added | DataViewRowState.Deleted | DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent | DataViewRowState.Unchanged);
var sortOrder = "";
var filterText = $"column= '{  columnValue }'";
var parameters = dataSet.Tables["childTable"].Select(filterText,sortOrder , desiredRowStates);
```